# waiting until recover value

Tags: sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to develop an offline mobile application using the PhoneGap framework. I am using the sqlite PhoneGap to access my local database.

My application uses 2 table, Table 1 contains values ​​and contains an identifier of the value in Table 2, to display the data I have to wait recuperation values ​​of table 2 with the function `recover_type_client` passing the value of  `IdClient`

how can I wait until I retrieve value `TXT` to display

```
function successDB(tx, results)
{
    for( var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++  )
    {
        TXT = recover_type_client(results.rows.item(i).IdClient )//Function 
        $("#tbod").append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="'+results.rows.item(value).IdPrestation+'"></td>'
                        +'<td> '+results.rows.item(value).RefPrestation                                               +' </td>'
                        +'<td> '+TXT                                                                      +' </td>'
                        +'<td> '+results.rows.item(value).CoordonneesAdressePrestation                                +' </td>'
                        +'<td> '+tab_client[i]  
                        +'</tr>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have use

```
   results.rows.item(value).IdPrestation
```

But value is not defined